# Estimate number of subsets

Tags: combinatorics

> Let $X_1,\cdots,X_m \in \binom{[n]}{k}, X_i \cup X_j \neq [n], X_i \neq X_j \
>  \forall 1 \leq i < j \leq m$.
>
> Show that $k \geq \frac{n}{2} \Rightarrow m \leq \left(1-
>  \frac{k}{n}\right)\binom{n}{k}$.

I thought about the [Erdős–Ko–Rado theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Ko%E2%80%93Rado_theorem). I take the set $\mathcal{X}' = \{X_1^c, \cdots, X_m^c\}, \mathcal{X}' \subseteq \binom{[n]}{n-k}$. $k \geq \frac{n}{2} \Rightarrow (n-k) \leq \frac{n}{2}$, so I can use the theorem for $\mathcal{X}'$ if I can show that $X_i^c \cap X_j^c \neq \emptyset \ \forall 1 \leq i < j \leq m$. The theorem says that $|\mathcal{X}'| \leq \binom{n-1}{(n-k)-1} = \binom{n-1}{n-k-1}$.

I do have two problems with that approach:

1. How do I show that $X_i^c \cap X_j^c \neq \emptyset \ \forall 1 \leq i < j \leq m$ applies?
2. How do I show that $\binom{n-1}{n-k-1} = \left(1-\frac{k}{n}\right)\binom{n}{k}$? I tried to rearrange it for some time, but still couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(1) for $1\leq i<j\leq m$,
$$\eqalign{X_i\cup X_j\ne [n]&\iff (X_i\cup X_j)^c\ne [n]^c\cr
&\iff  X_i^c\cap X_j^c\ne \emptyset\cr}$$
(2) $$\binom{n-1}{n-1-k}=\frac{(n-1)!}{k!(n-k-1)!}
=\frac{n-k}{n}\cdot\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}=\left(1-\frac{k}{n}\right)\binom{n}{k}.$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. There is only one thing that I don't understand: How to you get from $\frac{(n-1)!}{k!(n-k-1)!}$ to $\frac{n-k}{n}\cdot \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$?

Comment: @muffel, $(n-1)!=\frac{n!}{n}$, and $\frac{1}{(n-k-1)!}=\frac{n-k}{(n-k)!}$